# Tourist from Sweden visiting Philippines

Tags: paperwork, philippines, swedish-citizens

I understand Sweden is one of the countries with free visa entering Philippines, provided the tourist holds a valid passport and a round trip ticket. Do they need to have a proof of hotel or condo reservation?. What if the tourist will stay in my place, a residential place? Should I provide him/her an invitation letter?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Embassy of Philippines](http://www.philembassy.no/consular-services/visa), Swedish citizens can enter visa-free for up to 30 days, given they hold a passport valid for at least 6 months ad have a return or onward ticket. There is no requirement to provide proof of hotel bookings or an invitation letter.

From a practical point of view, it's of course good if the tourist is able to answer where they will be staying. If they are going to stay at your house or apartment, it's a good idea for the visitor to have the address and your contact information, for the unlikely event that immigration officials would want to verify by calling you.